# scraping udemy page with python but can't get access

Tags: python-3.x

I want to scrape udemy courses reviews but I can't get access to the page web.
when I want to read the page using python I get this error:

```
.
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Unauthorized
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: The website is blocking your scraper.

Answer (score 2):

403 means that you got forbidden from accessing the Udemy website because of your scrapper.
checks these links to get more info:
403 status code https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

robot.txt https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt

this is Udemy robot.txt link:
https://www.udemy.com/robots.txt